# Unable to find Approval Workflow in SharePoint 2010 Foundation

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow, sharepointfoundation2010

I'm new to SharePoint and I'd like to develop a Leave Form Application which utilizes the  Approval Workflow, but I cannot find it on SharePoint Foundation 2010. How can I enable it? I have already tried many methods which I found on Google, but I still have no clue. Please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer; as I was using SharePoint Foundation, there are now out-of-the-box workflows provided except for the three-state Workflow.

Comment: Hi @KishoreInWindows,  

So is there a way to import them to SharePoint Foundation?

Answer (score 1):

From your document library:

- Click library tab
- Click library settings tile
- Select Workflow Settings Link
- Click Add a Workflow link
- Approval should be in the Workflow Template list

If that doesn't work, check your site collection features and insure workflows is activated.

Comment: I already did the things,but none of them are working,may be it was not available in sharepoint foundation 2010

Answer (score 1):

Simple approval workflow can be activate ddirectly from library settings:

Go to your list->library settings in the ribbon->versionning settings->allow approval content option to yes...